# Default action performed by jQuery on the partial data in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-forms, getjson

I am attempting the following.
A customer select option in the main form. when a user selects a customer in the main form his bills should appear in the all the subsequent partials.

I am using ryan bates's nested_form gem to get the partial. the code is as follows.

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @money_receipt do |f| %>

    <div class="customers"><%= f.collection_select :customer_id, Customer.all, :id, :name, options ={:prompt => "-Select a Customer"}, :style=>'width:210px;'%></div><br />
    /*rest of the code*/

    <%= f.link_to_add "Add line items", :money_receipt_line_items %>
```

inside the partial

```
<div class="bill">
<%= f.collection_select :customer_bill_id, CustomerBill.all,:id,:id, {:prompt => "Select Customer bill"}, :style => 'width:202px;' %></div><br />

/*rest of the code*/
```

the jQuery code for the above is as follows

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(".customers select").bind("change", function() {
      var data = {
        customer_id: jQuery(this).val()  
      }
      jQuery.getJSON(
         "/money_receipts/get_bills",
        data, function(data){
      var result = "",a,x;
      var b = "<option>Select customer Bill</option>"
      for(i=0;i<data.length; i++)
      {
       a = data[i];
       result = result + "<option value="+a[0]+">"+a[0]+"</option>";
       console.log(result);
      }
     child=jQuery('.bill select').html(b+result);
    });
    });
  });
```

and finally in the controller i have. 
def get_bills

```
    @bill_amount = CustomerBill.find_all_by_customer_id(params[:customer_id]).map{|bill| [bill.id]} if params[:customer_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @bill_amount }
    end
  end
```

i was attempting to filter the bills and put in the div id `bill`. Now if i do a `console.log` in jQuery code i am getting the customer_id and the bills but i am not able to post it. if i do `console.log` on the `child` i get output as this `jQuery()`. where am i going wrong? is there a better way to achieve the above? guidance required. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

I personally prefer the way of putting HTML into partials instead of drawing it with JS code.

Like this:

`money_receipt.js:`

```
$('.customers select').change(function(){
  $.getScript('/money_receipts/get_bills?customer_id='+$(this).val())
})
```

`get_bills.js.erb:`

```
$('.bill select').html('<%=j render 'get_bills'%>')
```

`_get_bills.html.erb:`

```
<% @bills.each do |bill| %>
<option value="<%=bill.id%>"><%=bill.title%></option>
<% end %>
```

With fewer lines of code there are less places for errors to creep in.

Comment: Thank you, this is great :) but how to apply the above method for a nested form? correct me if i am wrong i believe this apply s to just one partial.